# How to extract chunks of information from a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, deep-copy, bytebuffer

I've a ByteBuffer that is populated via `socketChannel.read(buffer)`.

I want to extract information as byte[] or ByteBuffer that's located at specific position in this buffer.

It's being done like this at the moment:

```
byte[] data = new byte[length];
int oldPos = buffer.position();
buffer.position(offset);
buffer.get(data, 0, length);
buffer.position(oldPos);
```

I'd like to not create copies every time I want to extract information from the buffer. I've come up with the following approach. Please advise if there's a better way to accomplish this.

```
ByteBuffer readOnlyuplicate = orig.asReadOnlyBuffer();
readOnlyuplicate.position(start);
readOnlyuplicate.limit(start + length - 1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not create copies"? *Extracting* chunks of information mean to *copy* the information, optionally transforming too. --- And how is `duplicate()` supposed to be any better, given that is copies the content?

Comment: To not copy any bytes at all, access the backing array directly by calling [`array()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array--)

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers like C++, so you can only make a copy of the portion of the underlying array your interested in if that's what you need to do. However, since there is no (major) cost in copying the reference to the array around and just indexing into whatever part of the array you're interested in I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Andreas, I was under the impression that duplicate() only copied the state parameters and the underlying buffer remained the same because the javadoc says that duplicate() 'Creates a new byte buffer that shares this buffer's content. The content of the new buffer will be that of this buffer. ' I thought my solution is better because if my ByteBuffer is huge (say 16M), then I'd be duplicating few ints and not the entire underlying byte array. And lastly, the ByteBuffer is not backed by an array(), so I can't use array().

Comment: I read ByteBuffer's documentation again and would be happy to replace `duplicate()` with `asReadOnlyBuffer()`. Because it appears that the only difference b/w the output of these calls is that duplicate buffers allow the shared content to be modified and the read-only dups don't.